# How do I get PID from socket port on Windows?

Tags: c

Given a socket port how do you find the process ID (process name) of the process on Windows 10 that uses this port? I am aware of `netstat` command but I would like to do it with C code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about there, it appears there's a way: the IP Helper library.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/ip-helper-start-page

I haven't used it for this, but it's clearly going down the right road by providing everything you need to basically roll your own `netstat.exe`.

The low-level object that contains all the info is `MIB_TCPROW2`, which has the local and remote address + port, plus `dwOwningPid`. So we know there's a way.

Drilling down we ultimately need the `GetTcpTable2()` call, and Microsoft's web page helpfully has what appears to be fully-functional C code to do all this yourself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2

Finding this was the best surprise of my day!

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how did you go about finding this? I am interested in the mental process of your research:)

Comment: I used a disassembler (IDA Pro) on `netstat.exe` to find out how *it* did it.  The imports table showed some promising functions, so I then went to Bing. And there we have it.

Comment: Your how-to comment is even more valuable than the solution, thank you! However I ran into a new problem with accessing array returned by `GetTcpTable2` taking too long so I opened anther question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749053/how-to-subscribe-to-port-opening-or-port-closing-events-in-c  I would like to find out PID of each network packet that passes through (1000 per second).