# How to subscribe to port opening or port closing events in C?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I found out that you can use [`GetTcpTable2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2) to find out all TCP connection statuses. Unfortunately it takes 100ms to cycle through the array returned by `GetTcpTable2`(see example on the upper link). This is not acceptable because I would like to find out PID of each network packet that passes through (1000 per second).

Instead I would like to get notified when any TCP socket changes status to `LISTEN` or `CLOSED` and keep cache of opened ports.

Is it possible to subscribe to opening and closing events of any port on the system?

**UPDATE:** The goal is to identify which process is sending packets. IP packets that is. If you know the source port, you know the process that uses the socket. I'd like to make it as performant as possible, so I can use the web as usuall, but also keep a live track of what my computer is doing.

Comment: Please add more details to your question what you want to achieve. (What do you want to do when you know the PID related to a packet?) Partial answer based on some guessing: Maybe you don't need to parse the table for every packet. You could keep a cache of all connections with their PIDs and only re-parse the connection table when you find a packet that corresponds to an unknown connection. (And in regular intervals to remove old connections from your cache.) You could delay the parsing to ensure you don't do it more than N times per second and implement this it in a separate thread.

Comment: I m not sure I understand the question, but maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142038
It is a way to get the status of the `socket`

Comment: The goal is to identify which process is sending packets. IP packets that is. If you know the source port, you know the process that uses the socket. I'd like to make it as performant as possible, so I can use the web as usuall, but also keep a live track of what my computer is doing.

Comment: You say that the goal is to find out who's sending packets, but it might help if you said why you want to do this; what bigger problem are you trying to solve?   I doubt you're going to find any user-mode software to do what you're asking about.

Comment: There is no event (that I know of) which you can subscribe to for receiving this kind of info in real-time. You must poll the info periodically.