# Finding Process id of a process that connected through Unix Socket on Windows

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2, unix-socket

Unix Socket ported to Windows platform not so long ago but is there any method to get process id of connected process on windows same way you do using **getsockopt()** on linux and darwin ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PID from socket port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739009/how-do-i-get-pid-from-socket-port-on-windows)

Comment: Unix sockets do not expose a port to connect, it is a file like pipe.

Comment: Ah sorry, so you're using AF_UNIX sockets on Windows. Perhaps [query who has an open file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476625/windows-files-locked-by-process)?

Comment: This is a nice idea, I will try it and update here. Thanks.